# SharePoint 2010 Search crawl rules - how to exclude specific bdc entity by url

Tags: search, search-results, bdc-model, enterprise-search, custom-bdc

I've created searchable .net assembly connector, which reads text file (using this [post](http://toddbaginski.com/blog/how-to-create-a-searchable-sharepoint-2010-bdc-.net-assembly-connector-which-reads-from-a-flat-file/)). All works fine, content inside file was indexed and appears in search results.

I want to hide some rows from search results. In crawl log url to bdc entity looks like follows:

```
bdc3://flatfilelobsystem_flatfilelobsysteminstance/Default/00000000%2D0000%2D0000%2D0000%2D000000000000/3314/FlatFileLOBSystemInstance/3341?s_id=SBAAAAA==MwA=&s_ce=048u0h3o40800080g10200048u10003v55
```

I know that is possible to exclude some urls from crawling by specifying path (for example http://mysite/*) through crawl rules. I've added crawl rule with above url (with checked `Exclude complex URLs (URLs that contain question marks - ?)`), but after full crawl my entity doesn't excluded and still appears in search results. I've tried also this url (%2D decoded):

```
bdc3://flatfilelobsystem_flatfilelobsysteminstance/Default/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/3314/FlatFileLOBSystemInstance/3341?s_id=SBAAAAA==MwA=&s_ce=048u0h3o40800080g10200048u10003v55
```

with no luck.

Another part that I've tried - I created bcs model using SPD (that displays data from Customer table from AdventureWorks db), created profile page, next added model to content sources and perform full crawl. All fine, data appear in search results, profile page link work as expected.
Example of profile page link:

```
http://sp2010:80/sites/BDCProfile/_bdc/http___sp2010_sites_test/Customer_2.aspx?CustomerID=30118
```

I've also tried exclude this item using crawl rules and above url, but after full crawl item still appears in results (and no deletes in crawl log)...

So, the question is it possible to exclude bdc entity through crawl rules?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. This rule not working:

```
bdc3://flatfilelobsystem_flatfilelobsysteminstance/Default/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/3314/FlatFileLOBSystemInstance/3341?s_id=SBAAAAA==MwA=&s_ce=048u0h3o40800080g10200048u10003v55
```

So, you have to create profile page for your external content type. And exclusion rule works:

```
http://sp2010:80/sites/BDCProfile/_bdc/http___sp2010_sites_test/Customer_2.aspx?CustomerID=30118
```

In my first attempt I missed port (80, default, but it is required), after providing port and making full crawl my item was excluded.